# How do I remove an item from a Python list by value?

Tags: python, list

If I wanted to remove an item by its value instead of its index what would I do?

```
animals = ['tiger', 'snake', 'penguin','giraffe']
```

Say I wanted to remove `'penguin'` without typing `del animals[2]` how would I go about it?

I've tried typing `del animals['penguin']` but it doesn't work...

Comment: `animals['penguin']` means you are referencing a dictionary key `penguin`. You are having `animals` as `list` and not `dictionary`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
animals.remove("penguin")
```

Right? Granted it only removes the first value, but it will remove it by value not index. And will not require building a new list or require an extra call to lookup the index of the given value.

Answer (score 6):

You have to either find the index, or filter the list.

Finding the index:

```
del animals[animals.index('penguin')]
```

Or, you could just remove the value:

```
animals.remove('penguin')
```

where `list.remove()` is [documented](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) as being equilalent to the `del listobj[listobj.index(value)]` version above.

Either of these can raise an `IndexError` if `'penguin'` is not part of the list. If there is *more than one* copy of the value in the list, only the *first* such copy is removed.

Filtering would remove *all* such copies:

```
animals = [a for a in animals if a != 'penguin']
```

This will not raise an exception; it builds an entirely new list of values that are *not* equal to `'penguin'`.

Comment: @Ben filtering is the only one that will get all instances.

Comment: @JakobBowyer Good point - Martijn hadn't updated with the third option when I posted!

Answer (score 1):

One more way to filter the list which wasn't mentioned by Martijn Pieters is to use built-in [filter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
animals = filter(lambda x: x != 'penguin', animals)
```

Comment: I didn't mention it because it is essentially the same as the list comprehension but slower.

Comment: @MartijnPieters interesting, I didn't know it. thanks for the comment!